# VB.NET Event addressof

Tags: vb.net, events, callback, addressof

I would like to set up a callback that would be raised in my class by a different class:

```
Public Class CameraWindow
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control
        Private m_camera As Camera = Nothing

        ' Camera property
        <Browsable(False)> _
        Public Property Camera() As Camera
            Get
                Return m_camera
            End Get
            Set(value As Camera)
                ' lock
                Monitor.Enter(Me)

                ' detach event
                If m_camera IsNot Nothing Then
                    m_camera.NewFrame -= New EventHandler(AddressOf camera_NewFrame)
                    timer.[Stop]()
                End If

                m_camera = value
                needSizeUpdate = True
                firstFrame = True
                flash = 0

                ' atach event
                If m_camera IsNot Nothing Then
                    m_camera.NewFrame += New EventHandler(AddressOf camera_NewFrame)
                    timer.Start()
                End If

                ' unlock
                Monitor.[Exit](Me)
            End Set
        End Property

        ' On new frame ready
        Private Sub camera_NewFrame(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
            Invalidate()
        End Sub
```

The event is defined in

```
  Public Class Camera

        Public Event NewFrame As EventHandler
```

But VB.NET does not like the way I attach and detach the events.
Can somebody tell me how to do it correctly?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks as if you're normally using C#. In VB.NET you use the [`AddHandler` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx):

```
AddHandler m_camera.NewFrame, AddressOf camera_NewFrame
```

To remove the handler use [`RemoveHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xz97kac.aspx)

```
RemoveHandler m_camera.NewFrame, AddressOf camera_NewFrame
```

However, if the event handler is in a different class it need to be public:

```
Public Sub camera_NewFrame(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Invalidate()
End Sub
```

and you need an instance:

```
AddHandler Camera.NewFrame, AddressOf m_camera.camera_NewFrame
```